The consoles close
I have a problem with the terminals. In visual studio the terminal stays stuck, after a few seconds of running it does not write or let me write. The same thing happens with PowerShell and the command prompt, with the difference that after locking it closes. I've had this problem for a while now, if anyone could help me I would really appreciate it.
When I run a code in visual studio everything seems fine, but after a while it stops writing and gets stuck when it should continue writing. It also happens if I have to write in the terminal, it gets stuck and doesn't let me continue.
